# Apache Airflow SqlSensor

Tags: airflow, task, sensors, directed-acyclic-graphs

I trying to make SqlSensor to work with Oracle database, I've installed all the required provider and successfully tested the connection. When I run SqlSensor I got this error message

```
ERROR - Failed to execute job 32 for task check_exec_date (The connection type is not supported by SqlSensor. The associated hook should be a subclass of `DbApiHook`. Got OracleHook; 419)
```

I'm running Apache Airflow version 2.3.3 and installed Oracle provider apache-airflow-providers-oracle version 3.2.0

Comment: Do you have apache-airflow-providers-common-sql installed?

Comment: Hi @EladKalif, yes I've installed apache-airflow-providers-common-sql 1.0.0

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please open an issue in https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues with minimal reproduce example + full traceback so we can investigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

You are probably importing the sensor as:

```
from airflow.sensors import SqlSensor
```

Which cause the issue.
If you will import as

```
from airflow.providers.common.sql.sensors import SqlSensors
```

It will work.

**Full Details:**

There is a bug in `apache-airflow-providers-common-sql==1.0.0` which causes
`from airflow.sensors import SqlSensor` not to work properly.
The bug is fixed in https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/25293
thus upgrading to `apache-airflow-providers-common-sql>1.0.0` will allow also the old import style.
Regardless of the bug, you should use

```
from airflow.providers.common.sql.sensors import SqlSensors
```

as `from airflow.sensors import SqlSensor` is deprecated.

Comment: Noting that `apache-airflow-providers-common-sql>1.0.0` has not been released it. It will be released in the 1-3 weeks but to whoever comes with this problem simply use the provider import path as this is the proper solution to the problem.